# Backup database to file with CakePHP or normal PHP 

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I wrote a script to dump my database into a file but it involved querying the database, storing the results in an array and then using `fopen` and `fwrite` to write the file.

Since my database is very large it tries to allocate too much memory and fails.

Does anyone know a simple way to backup my database to an SQL file the same as a MySQL export would do, that won't use too much memory?

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If so, you can invoke mysqldump and dump everything directly to file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can run external programs on the server, you can try `mysqldump` - it makes a dump of the database specified, as a text file.

Example:

```
mysqldump -u someuser -p somepassword yourdatabase > /some/path/dump.sql
```

Comment: That's how I do it. It's run on cron.

Answer (score 1):

Yes use the `mysqldump` command, in PHP you can call it like:

```
shell_exec("mysqldump dbname > /some/path/dump.sql");
```

Answer (score 0):

An ideal solution would be to use the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) command line tool, as this is very low memory (especially if you're calling it via [system](http://www.php.net/system)/[exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), etc.) and is considerably more efficient that any "in-script" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? mysqldump is perfectly functional.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a cakephp console application which you can use to backup your database using a cron job or manually of course. https://bitbucket.org/mmahgoub/cakephp-backupme/

Just type the command `cake backup`

You can specify the rows returned per iteration to limit memory usage

`cakephp backup default 1000`

but it will take more time of course.